# 'Servers' view is missing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jee, eclipse-2020-03

I am very new to the advanced Java concepts. So I was trying to set up Apache tomcat in Eclipse but I don't find any 'servers' option under the 'show view' section. After running into this problem at first, I searched for some available solutions and found it would be helpful if I replace Eclipse for Java with Eclipse for JEE. And I did so with a hope for a quick resolve. But did not observe any change. Still there is no 'servers' option under 'show view'. Then I navigated to `Window > Show View > Others` and searched for 'server', only to end up finding nothing. Then as some other solutions to similar problems earlier suggested, I tried resetting perspective, but that did not help either. Also tried `Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other..` and `Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective...` although could not find anything relevant to servers. I then checked for server section in `Window>Preferences`, the 'Server' section which is probably supposed to be there is missing. For the record I have these installed as well,

```
JST Server Adapters
Identifier: org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group
Version: 3.2.600.v201910252115
```

```
JST Server Adapters Extensions
Identifier: org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.ext.feature.feature.group
Version: 3.3.700.v201910252115
```

```
Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
Identifier: org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group
Version: 3.16.0.v201910241808
```

```
Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
Identifier: org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group
Version: 3.15.0.v201908261515
```

My `java -version` output,

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

Eclipse version 2020-03, installed [eclipse-jee](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/eclipse-jee/) from the official Arch repository.

OS Specification: `Arch Linux`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the download from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-03/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers-includes-incubating-components ? There's the possibility that the Arch package isn't quite packaged correctly.

Comment: No problem there is one method that I use a lot. you can try pressing ctrl+shift+Q and again 'Q' instantly eclipse will give a popup window called Show View here you can type server it will list the window that will take you servers.

Comment: Installing the package from the official site solved the issue. @DANISHMALIM tried your solution in the Arch package, didn't work for me though.

Comment: Ok. Then we learned something new .I guess this issue might be in some other Arch based distros too Will try eclipse in manjaro.